# copy files in lakefs ctl recursively from lakefs in Docker

Tags: lakefs

I want to copy files from lakefs using lakefs ctl inside my own dockeg image.
If I use the command: RUN lakectl fs cp lakefs://-----/model model it works but it only copies files not recursively but I need to copy al files in all subdirectories.
If I use: RUN lakectl fs cp -recursive lakefs://-----/model model it doesn't work because this flag doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Command should be `lakectl fs upload --recursive` - please make sure you're using an up to date version of lakefs/lakectl (1.1.0 being the latest at the time of writing this. See https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/releases for the current latest release)